# deprecate unused virtual method

Tags: c++, deprecated

Here's an example to illustrate my issue :

```
class Foo1
{
  virtual void FooMethod() __attribute__((deprecated)) = 0;
};

class Foo2  : public Foo1
{
  virtual void FooMethod() = 0;
};
```

My class `Foo1` has a pure virtual method `FooMethod`. I don't want user to use it anymore. I want to make them use this method in the inherited class `Foo2`.
`Foo1::FooMethod()` is so deprecated and put in `Foo2` : `Foo2::FooMethod()`. `Foo2::FooMethod()` is then an override  of `Foo1::FooMethod();`

If the user try to overload `Foo1::FooMethod()`, he will get a compilation warning.
My issue is, if the user override `Foo2::FooMethod()`, he also gets a warning.

How can I implement "Overload `Foo1::FooMethod()` is deprecated, you must override  `FooMethod()` through `Foo2`". I can't delete `Foo1::FooMethod()` for compatibility.

Thanks !

Comment: That's not what deprecation is for, you're supposed to avoid that method entirely because it will disappear in a later version, so that includes overloading.

Comment: There are no overloads here.

Comment: First of all, you are not overloading, you are overriding. And you are always kind of overriding all of the base class versions, hence the warning.

Comment: Do you want a warning or an error?  If you can use an error you could make `FooMethod()` pure virtual in `Foo1`.

Comment: @Chad: It seems to me that it already is.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, You're right.  In that case, all child classes (that are actually concrete) have to override this method already.  So, what does it mean to be deprecated?

Comment: @Chad: Thats the better question; looks like someone designed himself into a corner. My best guess is that he wants to deprecate calling it through a pointer to Foo1, but not through a pointer to Foo2.

Comment: @Blindy, The only solution to don't have warning overriding FooMethod() in Foo2, is to don't deprecate the method in Foo1 and just comment Foo1 to explain the situation?

Answer (score -1):

> How can I implement "Overload Foo1::FooMethod() is deprecated, you must overload FooMethod() through Foo2". I can't delete Foo1::FooMethod() for compatibility.

At this point, you're causing such a mess in your design (:P) that I would stick with *documentation*.

*Tell* your users that the function is deprecated and shouldn't be used, then move on.