# C++: Deprecation warning when overriding a deprecated virtual method

Tags: c++, inheritance, constants, virtual, deprecation-warning

I have an pure virtual class that has a pure virtual method that should be `const`, but unfortunately is not. This interface is in a library, and the class is inherited by several other classes, in separate projects.

I'm trying to make this method `const` without breaking compatibility (at least for some time), but I cannot find a way to produce a warning when the non-const method is overloaded.

The following is an example of what I was able to produce so far:

- **Stage 0**: Before the change. Only the non-const version of `Interface::doSomething()` method exists and it is pure virtual.
- **Stage 1**: During the transition period. Both const and non-const versions of the `Interface::doSomething()` method exist. They both have a default implementation in order to allow both old style and new style implementations (they cannot be pure virtual in this stage, since each inherited class will override only one of them). The const version calls the non-const version in order to ensure compatibility with old implementations, the non-const version asserts, since it should never be called.
- **Stage 2**: Only the non-const version of `Interface::doSomething()` method exists and it is pure virtual.

In **Stage 1**, I'd expect to be able to produce a warning when a class overrides the non-const version of `Interface::doSomething()`, in order to warn the user that they should update their code, so that when I switch to **Stage 2** the chance to break other people's code is very low.
Unfortunately I cannot find a way to do that. I tried several combinations of flags, both with GCC and Clang. The only thing I was able to do, was to make the compilation fail (e.g. changing it to `final`), but that's not how I want to handle this. Is there a way to produce a warning?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface() = default;

// callDoSomething method:
// - stage 0: non const
// - stage 1-2: const
#if (STAGE == 0)
    void callDoSomething() { doSomething(); }
#else
    void callDoSomething() const { doSomething(); }
#endif

protected:

// non-const doSomething() method:
// - stage 0: pure virtual
// - stage 1: virtual with assert in default implementation (should never be called)
// - stage 2: removed
#if (STAGE == 0)
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
#elif (STAGE == 1)
    [[deprecated("Overload const version instead")]]
    virtual void doSomething()
    {
        assert(false);
    }
#endif

// const doSomething() method
// - stage 0: N/A
// - stage 1: virtual with default implementation (calls the non-const overload)
// - stage 2: pure virtual
#if (STAGE == 1)
    virtual void doSomething() const
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        std::cout << "  calling non const version\n";
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        const_cast<Interface*>(this)->doSomething();
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    }
#elif (STAGE == 2)
    virtual void doSomething() const = 0;
#endif
};


// Old style implementation: non-const doSomething()
// Allowed only in stages 0 and 1
#if (STAGE == 0 || STAGE == 1)
class Implementation_old : public Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Implementation_old() = default;

protected:
    virtual void doSomething() override
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }
};
# endif


// Old style implementation: const doSomething()
// Allowed only in stages 1 and 2
#if (STAGE == 1 || STAGE == 2)
class Implementation_new : public Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Implementation_new() = default;

protected:
    virtual void doSomething() const override
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }
};
#endif


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Interface* iface = nullptr;

#if (STAGE == 0 || STAGE == 1)
    iface = new Implementation_old;
    iface->callDoSomething();
    delete iface;
#endif

#if (STAGE == 1)
    std::cout << "-------------------\n";
#endif

#if (STAGE == 1 || STAGE == 2)
    iface = new Implementation_new;
    iface->callDoSomething();
    delete iface;
#endif

    iface = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the CMakeLists.txt file to build the example using the 3 definitions of `STAGE`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(test_deprecate_non_const)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_executable(main_stage_0 main.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(main_stage_0 PRIVATE STAGE=0)

add_executable(main_stage_1 main.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(main_stage_1 PRIVATE STAGE=1)

add_executable(main_stage_2 main.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(main_stage_2 PRIVATE STAGE=2)
```

Comment: compiler version and C++ standard?

Comment: This is out of scope, but I am curious, why would you want users to see a deprecation warning? I imagine the users will not have to modify their own code to ensure compatibility with the new code, a recompilation should be enough no?

Comment: Finaly I tested, I get the deprecated warning [here](https://godbolt.org/g/KuXoLS)

Comment: @Oliv your code shows the warning regardless of the user code. This way you will have library that emits the warning regardless of the the user does. This is a bad thing. The ideea is to show the warning iff the user code overrides the non-const method.

Comment: @bolov I tested several versions of gcc and clang on godbolt.org (just copy the code and add a `#define STAGE 1` at the top. The standard is c++14 (but I think that's necessary only for `[[deprecated]]`, the rest should be c++11

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the word "override" rather than "overload". Your code is also very far from minimal.

Comment: @n.m. You are right, sorry for the confusion. I fixed the title.

Comment: @Oliv The user will have to manually update the signature of the method in classes inheriting from the interface, from non-const to const, but they will not know they have to do that unless they read the documentation (but that is not going to happen) or they get a warning.

Comment: Even if you know that the function doesn't make sense for your class, you cannot in general know whether it makes sense for any derived class. Only authors of derived classes may decide.

Comment: As an alternative to a compiler warning, you could write a [`clang-tidy` check](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/#writing-a-clang-tidy-check). (Yes, I realize this requires telling your users to use your modified clang-tidy, which is not convenient at all.)

Answer (score 4):

It would be nice to have a warning on using a deprecated interface. However my attempts have failed as have yours. I think that unfortunately attributes were not designed with this in mind. I think an attribute applies to the name of an entity which means that you get the warning only when calling the method by name. But I did not study the standard about this.

So, with sadness in my heart I will steal a conclusion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21049735/2805305) to a mildly related post:

> *Tell* your users that the function is deprecated and shouldn't be used, then move on.