Can I get a compiler warning when the user overrides a deprecated callback?
I have a class like this:
class MyCallbacks
{
  protected:

    [[deprecated]] virtual void callback(int, int, const std::string &, double, int) {}

    virtual void callback(const Context & t_context)
    {
      // default implementation calls the old version for backward compatibility

      #pragma GCC diagnostic push
      #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

      callback(t_context.id, t_context.level, t_context.name, t_context.weight, t_context.specifics;

      #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    }
}

This lets existing code live in peace while giving the option to get the newer, better version of the callback that has richer data.
However, if someone accidentally overrode both versions of the method that would be bad.  I'd like to get a deprecation warning when overriding the deprecated callback, but at least in gcc and clang this doesn't seem to be covered by [[deprecated]].
Is there any way to do this, either with another attribute or via some clever trick?

OT: Instead of the new function calling the old deprecated function, I would have done it the opposite way.

@Someprogrammerdude doesn't seem possible (unless the new version of the callback is purely cosmetic and doesn't add new information).

@DanielMcLaury It depends on how you add the extra information. If new stuff is optional, you can easily reverse the order. If the new data is required and you cannot supply defaults, then we have a bigger problem. But the issue with your solution is that any user of MyCallbacks will get deprecation warning in their face, so they have to put the path for that header in system search path or disable the warning altogether.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50780894/gcc-deprecation-message-on-override says MSVC does the expected thing for once and warns on overriding the method. gcc and clang do not. I guess, as others concluded, your only option is to document that this overload is deprecated and move on.

@Yksisarvinen how can you reverse the order?  Say your old callback is like gotMessage(const std::string & t_message) and the new callback is like gotMessage(const std::string & t_message, time_t t_timestamp).  The calling code is going to have to call the latter, which means that it can't also call the former.

@Yksisarvinen In the actual code I turn off the warnings there, but I didn't include it here since it wasn't directly relevant to the question.  However I can add this to the code sample.

"if someone accidentally overrode both versions of the method". The deprecated one would never be called, not a big issue. If/when you remove the deprecated one (or mark it final as intermediate step), user code should be removed also.

@Jarod42 Imagine the following existing codebase
void callback(int, int, const std::string &, double, int) final { doVeryCriticalThing(); }
and then someone comes in, wants to add an action when this callback happens, looks at the docs, and writes
void callback(Context) final { writeLoglineForTiming(); }
They've now broken the program via spooky action at a distance, which I think is a bad thing to have happen without even a warning.

[[deprecated]] is implementation specific, so no guarantee of warnings, especially for non-trivial cases.
You might add a extra layer and deprecated the "old" interface:
namespace v2
{

class MyCallbacks
{
public:
    virtual ~MyCallbacks() = default;
    virtual void callback(const Context & t_context) = 0;
};

}

class [[deprecated]] MyCallbacks : v2::MyCallbacks
{
protected:

    [[deprecated]] virtual void callback(int, int, const std::string &, double, int) = 0;

    void callback(const Context & t_context) final
    {
      // default implementation calls the old version for backward compatibility
      #pragma GCC diagnostic push
      #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

      callback(t_context.id, t_context.level, t_context.name, t_context.weight, t_context.specifics);

      #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    }
};

Demo
So users inheriting from "old" MyCallbacks might get a warning (gcc seems not to warns :( )
And users using the new version (v2::MyCallbacks) won't be able to override the old API
